# Is there a Java class that lets me iterate through the last x elements?

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator

I am looking for something like a LinkedList with a function that returns an iterator for the last x elements.

For example:

```
LinkedList<Oky> obj;
obj.add(a);
obj.add(b);
obj.add(c, d, e, f, g );

Iterator<Oky> i = obj.iterator( 3 );
SYSOUT( i.next() == e );
SYSOUT( i.next() == f );
SYSOUT( i.next() == g );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`List.listIterator(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator-int-):

```
Iterator<Oky> it = obj.listIterator(obj.size() - 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ListIterator`:

```
obj.listIterator(obj.size()-3);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8

```
list.stream().skip(list.size() - 3).forEach(System.out::println);
```